# How to send Messages from Client to Server with ClientID with Pusher

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, pusher

I have configured Pusher Server on ASP.net MVC website as:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> HelloWorld() {
var options = new PusherOptions
{
  Cluster = "ap2",
  Encrypted = true
};

var pusher = new Pusher(
  "123",
  "ABC",
  "XYZ",
  options);

var result = await pusher.TriggerAsync(
  "my-channel",
  "my-event",
  new { message = "hello world" } );

  return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
 }
}
```

And I have made client in Java Swings as:

```
PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
options.setCluster("ap2");
Pusher pusher = new Pusher("XYZ", options);

Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");

channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
@Override
    public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, final String data) 
    {
      System.out.println(data);
    }
  });

pusher.connect();
```

This works fine and I receive the messages in Client JAVA app whenever I send any message from the Server.

But how can I send Messages from Client to the Server alongwith its ClientID?

Comment: Can you explain what it is you need instead of just down-voting? Looking at your code we see that you can trigger an event from the server side. But you wanted to send from the client and receive it in the backend, no?

Comment: Maybe my answer below was down-voted by someone because it did not specify how you make the call from client side. If you get it to work, maybe you can include that part in the question to help them out?

Comment: @RKrogh Yes understood, I will relpy to it once I am successful.

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways you can do this. If you have a token or cookie for your logged in users you can (and should) use those for sensitive data. Otherwise, to send data basically can be fitted in your http body and received by your endpoint as parameters or complex objects.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> HelloWorld(string foo, string bar) {
//Stuff goes here
}
```

Normally your content-type here is application/json but you can consume other types as well.

Then the body could simply look like:

```
{
   "foo":"Hello",
   "bar":"World"
}
```

Comment: You are right, I can call ActionResult of Server from Client code. Lemme work on it. Thanks mate.

Comment: No worries. Hope it helps. :)